# How to Split and Save Dropdown value which is inside RadGrid into two different columns of RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with 3 columns:
1) ID 
2) Account Code (Dropdown in Edit and Add mode) 
3) Description

In Edit & Add mode, Only "Account Code" column is visible and it is a Dropdown.
This Dropdown is bind with 2 values together (Account Code + Description)
So when user "Add" or "Edit" in RadGrid, Account Code dropdown appears
with combined value of (Account code + Description)

Ex: 1420.121620 - Acc Dep-IT Hardware Lease & HP 
           1420.133192 - Acc Dep-IT HP2 
           **(account code - description)**

**Now my requirement is:** when user selects any item from this Dropdown and then Click on "tick" button of RadGrid to Add new record or "Edit" button to Edit record, 'Account Code' should save in RadGrid's "Account code column" and 'Description' should save in RadGrid's "Description column", and visible inside RadGrid.

I tried using Split function but couldn't succeed.

Please reply how to achieve it. I am very new in Telerik controls.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the `selected` value in a `string` than you can separate the `accountNumber` and `accountName` like this.

```
string selectedValue = "1420.121620 - Acc Dep-IT Hardware Lease & HP";
string accNum  =  selectedValue.Substring(0, selectedValue.IndexOf('-')).Trim();
string accName = selectedValue.Substring(selectedValue.IndexOf('-') + 1).Trim();
```

To remove spaces from start or end use `.Trim()` method.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Your solution is working fine. Only 1 thing I want to ask that as you can see in my example: 
1420.121620 - Acc Dep-IT Hardware Lease & HP.  There is space after 'account code' number(1420.121620) and before 'description' (Acc Dep-IT Hardware Lease & HP) along with '-' . How to remove this space while doing Split ? Please reply

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I wanted the same.